# Database is connecting but not retrieving data

Tags: java, mysql, rest, api, jsp

I am trying to create a simple data retrieving program from the database. The connection is Successful but i get this error in the console `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver 
Connection Successful`

config file

```
 public class Config {

        public Connection connect() {
            Connection con = null;
            try {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

                con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appointment", "root", "");
                System.out.println("Connection Successful");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Connection unsuccessful");
                System.out.println("" + e);
            }

            return con;
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Config config = new Config();
        Connection con = config.connect();
        }

    }
```

Calling the database connection

```
public String readAppoinment() {
    String output = "";
    try {
        Connection con = config.connect();
        if (con == null) {
            return "Error while connecting to the database for reading appoinment details.";
        }
        output = "<table border=\"1\"><tr><th>Appointment Id</th><th>Appointment Date</th><th>Appointment Venue</th><th>Doctor Assign</th><th>Patient Id</th>"
                + "<th>Actions</th>";
        String query = "select * from appointment";
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while (rs.next()) {
            String appId = Integer.toString(rs.getInt("app_Id"));
            String appDate = rs.getString("app_Date");
            String appVenue = rs.getString("app_Venue");
            String docId = Integer.toString(rs.getInt("app_Doctor_Id"));
            String patientId = Integer.toString(rs.getInt("app_Patient_Id"));
```

I am getting

```
Error while connecting to the database
```

As a result in the browser.

Comment: The connection is not successful, you need to download mysql connector/j; install it and then add the jar file to your runtime classpath. "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" is the jdbc driver.

Comment: But I have added this to the buid path

Comment: The build path is distinct from the runtime classpath. And that particular error message means only one thing.

Comment: I tried it again but nothing happens i got the same error

Comment: How are you running your program? What commands? Are you using an IDE or the command line? Until you can add the correct jar to the runtime classpath, you will not be able to connect to your database.

Comment: Now i am getting this error `Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.`

Comment: Okay. That is a warning. And correct. You haven't needed `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` for some time, and they changed the name to "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"; it seems like you should now be able to connect. Are you getting a different error now?

Comment: This error is not showing in the config file it says connection successful but when i run the index.jsp file it prints connection unsuccessful

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and edit your question.

Comment: Question edited @ElliottFrisch

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in this code. Assuming this below code is in different class.

```
public String readAppoinment() {
        String output = "";
        try {
            Connection con = Config.connect(); // This should properly called
            if (con == null) {
                return "Error while connecting to the database";
            }
}
```

Comment: I think you missed "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

Comment: I think question is not properly framed. It also says "Connection Successful" which will be printed only when the line about println doesn't break.

Comment: Tried this @DharmendraVishwakarma

Comment: Also, as the title says "Database is connecting but not retrieving data", where have you written a query to fetch record from the DB. You need to build a statement and perform a select query to fetch records.